# How to get a split %var:~1,-2% with a ! or % in the string to echo correctly to a file. DELAYEDEXPANSION issue?

Tags: cmd

The **:FileContent** function near the bottom is where the variable I'm having issues with is.

**!onlineplayer!** is the variable I need to pass a string that may include `!` or `%` to a file via `>>`

Output I want:

```
`5John `%Wheeler
```

Output I get:

```
`5John `Wheeler
```

I need to pipe the value to a text file (PowerShell) for execution at the end of the script.

Everything works correctly, until I use a value containing a `!` or a `%`, then not surprisingly I end up getting empty space where they are supposed to be, normally I would just escape/double `^!` or `%%` but I have no control over the var value and I´m not sure if I should make a new section that tries to inject another `%` into the `txt` file if its detected, or if this already works but just has an expansion issue? I don´t know that an injection route would be easier or without problems.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CLS
CD /d %~dp0
SET titlename=UpdatingScoreboard
IF EXIST QUEUESB (
    TASKLIST /V /NH /FI "imagename eq cmd.exe"| find /I /C "%titlename%" > nul
    IF %errorlevel%==0 exit /b
    DEL QUEUESB /F /Q >nul
)
TITLE %titlename%
IF EXIST UPDATINGSB GOTO INPROGRESS

:BEGIN
ECHO.>UPDATINGSB
SET UPLAYER=0
SET ACTIVENODES=0
SET NODENUM=1
SET MAXNODES=50
SET "lordfolder=C:\mystic\doors\lord"
SET "webfolder=C:\xampp\htdocs\gamedata"
CALL :newfile
CALL :fileheader

:checkdrops
IF %NODENUM% GTR %MAXNODES% GOTO completed
set "pathtodoorsys=C:\mystic\temp%NODENUM%\door.sys"
IF EXIST %pathtodoorsys% (
    SET /A ACTIVENODES=%ACTIVENODES%+1
    GOTO initsearch
)
SET /A NODENUM=%NODENUM%+1
goto checkdrops

:initsearch
set player=0
set prevplayer=0

:startdump
playtext r %player% %player% %lordfolder%
if %player% GEQ 1 (
    fc playtext.%prevplayer% playtext.%player%>searching.tmp1
    more +9 searching.tmp1>searching.tmp2
    set /a prevplayer=%prevplayer%+1
)
set /a player=%player%+1
if not exist searching.tmp2 goto startdump
for %%R in (searching.tmp2) do if not %%~zR lss 1 goto startdump
set /a player=%player%-1
set /a prevplayer=%prevplayer%-1
del playtext.%player% /f /q >nul
del playtext.%prevplayer% /f /q >nul
DEL searching.tm* /F /Q >nul
set /a prevplayer=%prevplayer%-1
CALL :get-activeuser activeuser

:parsenames
IF NOT EXIST "playtext.%prevplayer%" SET /A NODENUM=%NODENUM%+1 & SET /A UPLAYER=%UPLAYER%+1 & goto checkdrops
CALL :get-username username
IF /I "%activeuser%"=="%username:~9,-2%" (
    CALL :get-playername playername
    SET "onlineplayer=!playername:~5!"
    CALL :filecontent
    SET /A NODENUM=%NODENUM%+1
    goto checkdrops
)
IF /I "%activeuser%"=="%username:~9,-1%" (
    CALL :get-playername playername
    SET "onlineplayer=!playername:~5!"
    CALL :filecontent
    SET /A NODENUM=%NODENUM%+1
    goto checkdrops
)
set /a prevplayer=%prevplayer%-1
GOTO parsenames

:get-activeuser
for /f "skip=9 eol= delims=" %%a in ('type "%pathtodoorsys%"') do (
    set "%1=%%a"
    exit /b
)
exit /b

:get-username
for /f "skip=2 eol= delims=" %%a in ('type "playtext.%prevplayer%"') do (
    set "%1=%%a"
    exit /b
)
exit /b

:get-playername
for /f "skip=1 eol= delims=" %%a in ('type "playtext.%prevplayer%"') do (
    set "%1=%%a"
    exit /b
)
exit /b

:completed
SET NODENUM=0
SET MAXUSERS=150
IF NOT %ACTIVENODES% GTR 0 (
    ECHO ^0>"%webfolder%\online.txt"
    call :filefooter
    call :cleanup
    more +4 "%lordfolder%\score.ans" > "%lordfolder%\score.tmp"
    powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file "%~dp0showonline.ps1"
    del "%lordfolder%\score.tmp" /f /q >nul
    del "%~dp0showonline.ps1" /f /q >nul
    IF EXIST QUEUESB (
        DEL QUEUESB /F /Q >nul
    ) else (
        DEL UPDATINGSB /F /Q >nul
    )
    exit /b
) ELSE (
    ECHO ^1>"%webfolder%\online.txt"
    call :filefooter
    call :cleanup
    more +4 "%lordfolder%\score.ans" > "%lordfolder%\score.tmp"
    powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file "%~dp0showonline.ps1"
    IF %uplayer% GEQ 1 (
        CALL :uplayer
    )
    del "%lordfolder%\score.tmp" /f /q >nul
    del "%~dp0showonline.ps1" /f /q >nul
    IF EXIST QUEUESB (
        DEL QUEUESB /F /Q >nul
    ) else (
        DEL UPDATINGSB /F /Q >nul
    )
    exit /b
)

:cleanup
if %NODENUM% GTR %MAXUSERS% exit /b
if exist playtext.%NODENUM% del playtext.%NODENUM% /F /Q >nul
set /a NODENUM=%NODENUM%+1
goto cleanup
exit /b

:NEWFILE
IF EXIST showonline.ps1 DEL showonline.ps1 /F /Q >nul
exit /b

:FILEHEADER
ECHO Get-Content %lordfolder%\score.tmp ^| ForEach-Object {>> showonline.ps1
ECHO $line = $_>> showonline.ps1
ECHO $line = $_ -replace ' ', '^&nbsp;' -replace '(\x1B)', '' -replace '(\[)', '' -replace '0;30m', '^</font^>^<font color="Black"^>' -replace '0;31m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkRed"^>' -replace '0;32m', '^</font^>^<font color="Green"^>' -replace '0;33m', '^</font^>^<font color="Orange"^>' -replace '0;34m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkBlue"^>' -replace '0;35m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkMagenta"^>' -replace '0;36m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkCyan"^>' -replace '0;37m', '^</font^>^<font color="Gray"^>' -replace '1;30m', '^</font^>^<font color="DimGray"^>' -replace '1;31m', '^</font^>^<font color="Red"^>' -replace '1;32m', '^</font^>^<font color="LightGreen"^>' -replace '1;33m', '^</font^>^<font color="Yellow"^>' -replace '1;34m', '^</font^>^<font color="Blue"^>' -replace '1;35m', '^</font^>^<font color="Magenta"^>' -replace '1;36m', '^</font^>^<font color="Cyan"^>' -replace '1;37m', '^</font^>^<font color="White"^>' -replace '-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-', '^<font color="LightGreen"^>-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-^</font^>' -replace '^&nbsp;^</font^>^<font color="White"^>On', '^</font^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>On^</font^>' -replace '\S^+$','$^&^<br^>' -replace 'Alive^<br^>','Alive^&nbsp;^<br^>'>> showonline.ps1
exit /b

:FILECONTENT
ECHO $a = "!onlineplayer!">> showonline.ps1
ECHO $a = $a.replace('`0','\x1B\[1;32m').replace('`1','\x1B\[0;34m').replace('`2','\x1B\[0;32m').replace('`3','\x1B\[0;36m').replace('`4','\x1B\[0;31m').replace('`5','\x1B\[0;35m').replace('`6','\x1B\[0;33m').replace('`7','\x1B\[0;37m').replace('`8','\x1B\[1;30m').replace('`9','\x1B\[1;34m').replace('`#','\x1B\[1;35m').replace('`\$','\x1B\[1;33m').replace('`@','\x1B\[1;31m').replace('`^^!','\x1B\[1;36m').replace('`%%','\x1B\[1;37m')>> showonline.ps1
ECHO if ($_ -like "*$a*") {>> showonline.ps1
ECHO $line = $_ -replace ' ', '^&nbsp;' -replace '(\x1B)', '' -replace '(\[)', '' -replace '0;30m', '^</font^>^<font color="Black"^>' -replace '0;31m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkRed"^>' -replace '0;32m', '^</font^>^<font color="Green"^>' -replace '0;33m', '^</font^>^<font color="Orange"^>' -replace '0;34m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkBlue"^>' -replace '0;35m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkMagenta"^>' -replace '0;36m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkCyan"^>' -replace '0;37m', '^</font^>^<font color="Gray"^>' -replace '1;30m', '^</font^>^<font color="DimGray"^>' -replace '1;31m', '^</font^>^<font color="Red"^>' -replace '1;32m', '^</font^>^<font color="LightGreen"^>' -replace '1;33m', '^</font^>^<font color="Yellow"^>' -replace '1;34m', '^</font^>^<font color="Blue"^>' -replace '1;35m', '^</font^>^<font color="Magenta"^>' -replace '1;36m', '^</font^>^<font color="Cyan"^>' -replace '1;37m', '^</font^>^<font color="White"^>' -replace '^&nbsp;^</font^>^<font color="White"^>On', '^</font^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>On^</font^>' -replace '\S^+$','$^&^<br^>' -replace 'Alive^<br^>','Alive^&nbsp;^<br^>' -replace 'Alive^&nbsp;^<br^>', 'Alive^&nbsp;^</font^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>On^</font^>^<br^>' -replace 'Dead^&nbsp;^<br^>', 'Dead^&nbsp;^&nbsp;^</font^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>On^</font^>^<br^>'>> showonline.ps1
ECHO }>> showonline.ps1
exit /b

:FILEFOOTER
ECHO $line>> showonline.ps1
ECHO ^} ^| Set-Content %webfolder%\score.shtml>> showonline.ps1
exit /b

:uplayer
ECHO ^<br^>^<center^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>A hero is approaching.. Will they join our ranks^?^</font^>^</center^>>>%webfolder%\score.shtml
exit /b

:INPROGRESS
IF NOT EXIST QUEUESB ECHO.>QUEUESB
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
SET /A WAITEDTIME=%WAITEDTIME%+1
IF %WAITEDTIME% GEQ 8 DEL UPDATINGSB /F /Q >nul
IF EXIST UPDATINGSB GOTO INPROGRESS
DEL QUEUESB /F /Q >nul
GOTO BEGIN
```

**FIXED BY MOVING DELAYED EXPANSION TO OUTPUT SECTION ONLY**
Updated working code with some of the commented fixes applied. I can improve it more but I need to make sure what im doing with it isnt a waste of time first, please excuse the sloppyness.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
SET "ramdisk=B:\"
CD /d "%~dp0"
SET titlename=UpdatingScoreboard
IF EXIST "%ramdisk%QUEUESB" (
TASKLIST /V /NH /FI "imagename eq cmd.exe"| find /I /C "%titlename%" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 exit /b
DEL "%ramdisk%QUEUESB" /F /Q >nul
)
TITLE %titlename%
IF EXIST "%ramdisk%UPDATINGSB" GOTO INPROGRESS
:BEGIN
ECHO.>"%ramdisk%UPDATINGSB"
SET UPLAYER=0
SET ACTIVENODES=0
SET NODENUM=1
SET MAXNODES=50
SET "lordfolder=C:\mystic\doors\lord"
SET "scorefile=%lordfolder%\score.ans"
SET "webfolder=C:\xampp\htdocs\gamedata"
CALL :fileheader
:checkdrops
IF %NODENUM% GTR %MAXNODES% GOTO completed
set "pathtodoorsys=C:\mystic\temp%NODENUM%\door.sys"
IF EXIST %pathtodoorsys% (
SET /A ACTIVENODES+=1
GOTO initsearch
)
SET /A NODENUM+=1
goto checkdrops
:initsearch
set player=0
set prevplayer=0
:startdump
CD /d "%ramdisk%"
"%~dp0playtext.exe " r %player% %player% %lordfolder%""
CD /d "%~dp0
if %player% GEQ 1 (
fc "%ramdisk%playtext.%prevplayer%" "%ramdisk%playtext.%player%">"%ramdisk%searching.tmp1"
more +9 "%ramdisk%searching.tmp1">"%ramdisk%searching.tmp2"
set /a prevplayer+=1
)
set /a player+=1
if not exist "%ramdisk%searching.tmp2" goto startdump
for %%R in (%ramdisk%searching.tmp2) do if not %%~zR lss 1 goto startdump
set /a player-=1
set /a prevplayer-=1
del "%ramdisk%playtext.%player%" /f /q >nul
del "%ramdisk%playtext.%prevplayer%" /f /q >nul
DEL "%ramdisk%searching.tm*" /F /Q >nul
set /a prevplayer-=1
CALL :get-activeuser activeuser
:parsenames
IF NOT EXIST "%ramdisk%playtext.%prevplayer%" SET /A NODENUM+=1 & SET /A UPLAYER+=1 & goto checkdrops
CALL :get-username username
CALL :trim loginname %username:~9%
IF /I "%activeuser%"=="%loginname%" (
CALL :get-playername playername
CALL :filecontent
SET /A NODENUM+=1
goto checkdrops
)
set /a prevplayer-=1
GOTO parsenames
:get-activeuser
for /f "usebackq skip=9 eol= delims=" %%a in ("%pathtodoorsys%") do (
set "%1=%%a"
exit /b
)
exit /b
:get-username
for /f "usebackq skip=2 eol= delims=" %%a in ("%ramdisk%playtext.%prevplayer%") do (
set "%1=%%a"
exit /b
)
exit /b
:get-playername
for /f "usebackq skip=1 eol= delims=" %%a in ("%ramdisk%playtext.%prevplayer%") do (
set "%1=%%a"
exit /b
)
exit /b
:trim
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET trim=%*
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ("!trim!") DO ENDLOCAL & set %1=%%b
exit /b
:completed
SET NODENUM=0
SET MAXUSERS=150
IF NOT %ACTIVENODES% GTR 0 (
ECHO ^0>"%webfolder%\online.txt"
call :filefooter
call :cleanup
more +4 "%scorefile%" > "%ramdisk%score.tmp"
powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file "%ramdisk%showonline.ps1"
del "%ramdisk%score.tmp" /f /q >nul
del "%ramdisk%showonline.ps1" /f /q >nul
IF EXIST "%ramdisk%QUEUESB" (
DEL "%ramdisk%QUEUESB" /F /Q >nul
) else (
DEL "%ramdisk%UPDATINGSB" /F /Q >nul
)
exit /b
) ELSE (
ECHO ^1>"%webfolder%\online.txt"
call :filefooter
call :cleanup
more +4 "%scorefile%" > "%ramdisk%score.tmp"
powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file "%ramdisk%showonline.ps1"
IF %uplayer% GEQ 1 (
CALL :uplayer
)
del "%ramdisk%score.tmp" /f /q >nul
del "%ramdisk%showonline.ps1" /f /q >nul
IF EXIST "%ramdisk%QUEUESB" (
DEL "%ramdisk%QUEUESB" /F /Q >nul
) else (
DEL "%ramdisk%UPDATINGSB" /F /Q >nul
)
exit /b
)
:cleanup
if %NODENUM% GTR %MAXUSERS% exit /b
if exist "%ramdisk%playtext.%NODENUM%" del "%ramdisk%playtext.%NODENUM%" /F /Q >nul
set /a NODENUM+=1
goto cleanup
exit /b
:FILEHEADER
ECHO Get-Content "%ramdisk%score.tmp" ^| ForEach-Object {> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
ECHO $line = $_>> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
ECHO $line = $_ -replace ' ', '^&nbsp;' -replace '(\x1B)', '' -replace '(\[)', '' -replace '0;30m', '^</font^>^<font color="Black"^>' -replace '0;31m', '^</font^>^<font color="#b30000"^>' -replace '0;32m', '^</font^>^<font color="Green"^>' -replace '0;33m', '^</font^>^<font color="Orange"^>' -replace '0;34m', '^</font^>^<font color="Blue"^>' -replace '0;35m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkMagenta"^>' -replace '0;36m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkCyan"^>' -replace '0;37m', '^</font^>^<font color="Silver"^>' -replace '1;30m', '^</font^>^<font color="DimGray"^>' -replace '1;31m', '^</font^>^<font color="#ff4d4d"^>' -replace '1;32m', '^</font^>^<font color="#00cc00"^>' -replace '1;33m', '^</font^>^<font color="Yellow"^>' -replace '1;34m', '^</font^>^<font color="#4d4dff"^>' -replace '1;35m', '^</font^>^<font color="#ff66ff"^>' -replace '1;36m', '^</font^>^<font color="Cyan"^>' -replace '1;37m', '^</font^>^<font color="White"^>' -replace '^&nbsp;^</font^>^<font color="White"^>On', '^</font^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>On^</font^>' -replace '\S^+$','$^&^<br^>' -replace 'Alive^<br^>','Alive^&nbsp;^<br^>' -replace '^</font^>^<font color="#00cc00"^>-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-^<br^>','^</font^>^<div id="headerline"^>^<font color="#00cc00"^>-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-^</font^>^</div^>'>> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
exit /b
:FILECONTENT
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO $a = '!playername:~5!'>> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
ENDLOCAL
ECHO $a = $a.replace(' ','^*').replace('`0','^*').replace('`1','^*').replace('`2','^*').replace('`3','^*').replace('`4','^*').replace('`5','^*').replace('`6','^*').replace('`7','^*').replace('`8','^*').replace('`9','^*').replace('`#','^*').replace('`\$','').replace('`@','').replace('`!','^*').replace('`%%','^*') >> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
ECHO if ($_ -like "*$a*") {>> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
ECHO $line = $_ -replace ' ', '^&nbsp;' -replace '(\x1B)', '' -replace '(\[)', '' -replace '0;30m', '^</font^>^<font color="Black"^>' -replace '0;31m', '^</font^>^<font color="#b30000"^>' -replace '0;32m', '^</font^>^<font color="Green"^>' -replace '0;33m', '^</font^>^<font color="Orange"^>' -replace '0;34m', '^</font^>^<font color="Blue"^>' -replace '0;35m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkMagenta"^>' -replace '0;36m', '^</font^>^<font color="DarkCyan"^>' -replace '0;37m', '^</font^>^<font color="Silver"^>' -replace '1;30m', '^</font^>^<font color="DimGray"^>' -replace '1;31m', '^</font^>^<font color="#ff4d4d"^>' -replace '1;32m', '^</font^>^<font color="#00cc00"^>' -replace '1;33m', '^</font^>^<font color="Yellow"^>' -replace '1;34m', '^</font^>^<font color="#4d4dff"^>' -replace '1;35m', '^</font^>^<font color="#ff66ff"^>' -replace '1;36m', '^</font^>^<font color="Cyan"^>' -replace '1;37m', '^</font^>^<font color="White"^>' -replace '^&nbsp;^</font^>^<font color="White"^>On', '^</font^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>On^</font^>' -replace '\S^+$','$^&^<br^>' -replace 'Alive^<br^>','Alive^&nbsp;^<br^>' -replace 'Alive^&nbsp;^<br^>', 'Alive^&nbsp;^</font^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>On^</font^>^<br^>' -replace 'Dead^&nbsp;^<br^>', 'Dead^&nbsp;^&nbsp;^</font^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>On^</font^>^<br^>'>> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
ECHO }>> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
exit /b
:FILEFOOTER
ECHO $line>> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
ECHO ^} ^| Set-Content %webfolder%\score.shtml>> %ramdisk%showonline.ps1
exit /b
:uplayer
ECHO ^<br^>^<center^>^<font class="blink" color="Red"^>A hero is approaching.. Will they join our ranks^?^</font^>^</center^>>>%webfolder%\score.shtml
exit /b
:INPROGRESS
IF NOT EXIST "%ramdisk%QUEUESB" ECHO.>"%ramdisk%QUEUESB"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
SET /A WAITEDTIME+=1
IF %WAITEDTIME% GEQ 8 DEL "%ramdisk%UPDATINGSB" /F /Q >nul
IF EXIST "%ramdisk%UPDATINGSB" GOTO INPROGRESS
DEL "%ramdisk%QUEUESB" /F /Q >nul
GOTO BEGIN
```

Comment: `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` as first line in the `:filecontent` subroutine and `endlocal` right before the `exit /b` to disable delayed expansion and make the `!` (temporarily) a "normal" char again.

Comment: The main problem is `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` in second line resulting on line `set "%1=%%a"` in `for` loop of `:get-playername` that the string read from the text file and assigned to loop variable `a` is parsed a second time with interpreting `!` as beginning/end of an environment variable reference before assigned the reparsed string to the environment variable `playername`. The entire code is full of mistakes starting from fourth line which fails already if the directory path of the batch file contains `&`. There is a complete rewrite necessary to fix this batch file.

Comment: `CD /d %~dp0` should be `CD /d "%~dp0"`. `IF %errorlevel%==0 exit /b` in eight line should be `if not errorlevel 1 exit /b` to work at all as otherwise the condition checks the exit code assigned to __dynamic__ variable `ERRORLEVEL` __before__ running `IF EXIST QUEUESB`. Regarding to `ECHO.>UPDATINGSB` see DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) `SET /A ACTIVENODES=%ACTIVENODES%+1` should be `SET /A ACTIVENODES+=1` according to usage help of __SET__ output on running `set /?` in a cmd window.

Comment: The other __arithmetic expressions__ should be modified in a similar way. All `for /f "..."` with `('type "file name"')` should be `for /f "usebackq ..."` with `("file name")` to process the text files directly without running in background one more `cmd.exe` just to use its internal command `type` to output a text file and process the captured output, except the text files are UTF-16 encoded which is most likely not the case ever.

Comment: The solution for the main problem requires as second line `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` and use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) only where really needed. It looks like delayed variable expansion is not necessary in the entire batch file with a redesign of the __IF__ conditions to avoid command blocks by changing the conditions to the opposite and use __GOTO__ even more often.

Comment: @Mofi I added a function in the updated code called :TRIM to trim the whitespace from the ends of the username var. I am using delayed expansion there as well. I'm noticing I only close expansion off in the FOR loop and use an & to set the var, should I just set the var and drop to the next line to endlocal? In case the username var is empty? No problems here yet but just noticed it.. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping only a single line in the :FILECONTENT function with delayed expansion resolved the issue. OP updated. I could not have solved this without the comments. Thank you!

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO $a = "!playername:~5!">> showonline.ps1
ENDLOCAL
```